# Multiple SQL statements in flyway.initSql

Tags: flyway

Is something like this possible and if yes, is initSql executed each time a connection is established? For example i want to make sure that on each connection the time zone is set to UTC. Or is there a better way to execute connection-init-sql statements?

```
flyway:
  datasources:
      default:
          initSql: SET ROLE test_role; SET time zone 'UTC'; <--- is this second statement executed?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, initsql supports multiple statements. It is run "[to initialize a new database connection immediately after opening it](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/initSql)," so yes, it's run each time a connection is established.

For example, against a test SQL Server database, I ran:

`flyway -initSql="select 1; select 2" info`

This output the normal content of flyway info, but also included the following after the usual connection info header:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did solve my issue just like you explained :)